# Multi-Dimension Matrix Matmul Rule

Tags: numpy, pytorch, matmul

Can I safely assume that when

```
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d ... n-1,n]) and Y = torch.rand([e,f,...k-1,k])
if X[n] = Y[k-1] then X and Y can execute torch.matmul calculation
```

or when Y only has one dimension Y[k]

```
if X[n] = Y[k] then X and Y can execute torch.matmul calculation
```

for example:
In 2 dimension matrix

```
X = torch.rand([a,b]), Y = torch.rand([e,f])
it's very easy to tell whether X and Y can do torch.matmul() calculations
If b = e, then yes otherwise no.
```

In 3 dimension matrix

```
X = torch.rand([a,b,c]), Y = torch.rand([e,f,g])
if c = f then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.
```

In 4 dimensions matrix

```
Scenario 1:
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d]), Y = torch.rand([e,f,g,h])
if d = g then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.

Scenario 2:
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d]), Y = torch.rand([e,f,g])
if d = f then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.

Scenario 2:
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d]), Y = torch.rand([e,f,g])
if d = f then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.

Scenario 3:
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d]), Y = torch.rand([e,f])
if d = e then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.

Scenario 4:
X = torch.rand([a,b,c,d]), Y = torch.rand([e])
if d = e then result = torch.matmul(X,Y) is valid otherwise no.
```

Comment: For the last 2 dimensions, you seem to have things right (last of A pairs with 2nd to last of B).  But the leading dimensions have to `broadcast`.  Choose a,b,c,...=2,3,4,....etc, and let the computer verify  or disprove your dedfuctions.